# textfield validator getting error the Lengthvalidator.maximumLength(15) is undefined for type String

Tags: wicket

Here is my example:

```
TextField t1 = new RequiredTextField("name", new PropertyModel(this,"name")
                   .add(LengthValidator.maximumLength()));
TextField t2 = new TextField("email", new PropertyModel(this,"email"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`LengthValidator` is deprecated. You should use `StringValidator`.

For example:

`StringValidator.maximumLength(15);`